# C++ GTK make MinGW error simple program

Tags: c++, gtk, makefile, mingw

I really need help on getting a simple GTK program in c++ running using MinGW. Here's my program:

```
# Makefile for Hello World Program (lab0).

all: lab0

lab0: lab0.o
    g++ -Wall lab0.o -o lab0 -L C:/Users/Vic/Desktop/MinGW/lib -lgtk

lab0.o: lab0.c
    g++ -Wall -I C:/Users/Vic/Desktop/MinGW/include/gtk-2.0/gtk -c lab0.c -o lab0.o
```

Program:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

 int main (int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *label;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    /* create the main, top level, window */
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    /* give it the title */
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Hello World");

    /* Connect the destroy signal of the window to gtk_main_quit
     * When the window is about to be destroyed we get a notification and
     * stop the main GTK+ loop
     */
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    /* Create the "Hello, World" label  */
    label = gtk_label_new ("Hello, World");

    /* and insert it into the main window  */
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), label);

    /* make sure that everything, window and label, are visible */
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    /* start the main loop, and let it rest there until the application is closed */
    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
 }
```

when i compile this using minGW i get this error:

```
g++ -Wall lab0.o -o lab0 -LC:/users/vic/desktop/mingw/lib -lgtk
/bin/Id: cannot find -lgtk
collect2: Id returned 1 exit status
make: *** [lab0] Error 1
```

I need to fix this problem and I need to figure out how to run gtk from my makefile.

Comment: Do you have the libgtk installed in your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would use **pkg-config** to help you find the header and library paths:

```
g++ -Wall lab0.o -o lab0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-win32-2.0`
```

Or just the library path:

```
g++ -Wall lab0.o -o lab0 -LC:/users/vic/desktop/mingw/lib -lgtk `pkg-config --libs gtk+-win32-2.0`
```

Comment: You could also just fix the gtk linkage on your cmd, which should be `-lgtk+-win32-2.0`

Comment: i have pkg=config.. how do i use it? just put this command in the makefile and it will work? i dont have to use some other seperate pckage program?

Comment: ok so i tried typing the pkg-config commands you gave me and they dont work. I get this error: /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found, etc   maybe I am doing my makefile wrong? Can you give me a makefile that uses pkg that will apply to my situation plz? thanks

Comment: @user593301 First of all, I'm assuming you have gtk+ 2.0 installed. According to you, MingW libs are located at `C:/users/vic/desktop/mingw/lib`. Try to locate gtk+ 2.0 DLL in there. If you can't find it, then probably you don't have gtk installed on your system.

Comment: I do have gtk 2 installed along with glib, etc.